# YouTube API not returning full description

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, gdata

I'm currently using the YouTube API V2 inside my iOS app, however the description seems to be bugged and cuts off. It never returns the full description. It always stops at `...`. I've never had this issue before, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or what YouTube did to their API ?

Here's the API request I'm calling : http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/DaveDays/uploads?q=&v=2&start-index=1&max-results=50&orderby=published&time=this_week

Example: Instead of returning this description

```
This is Dave's reaction/parody to Miley Cyrus video We Can't Stop. 
iTunes: https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/we-...

Twitter: http://www.twitter.com/davedays
Facebook: http://www.facebook.com/ddays
Instagram: http://www.instagram.com/davedays
Merch!! http://www.westaspenmerch.com/davedays

Credits:
Chris http://www.youtube.com/iamchrisc
Nikki http://www.youtube.com/nikkinhollywood
Joey: http://www.youtube.com/bambamjoey
Matt: http://www.youtube.com/matthewdamc

Parody of Miley Cyrus' song We Can't Stop! Twerking it upp! Hi Miley Cyrus. We can't stop either. Miley Cyrus.
```

it returns this one

```
This is Dave's reaction/parody to Miley Cyrus video We Can't Stop. iTunes: https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/we-cant-stop-parody-single/id685057235 Twitter: ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you think its a bug, then check and report it at: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list?q=label:API-YouTube

If additional parameters changes the request into a search request, then it will give a short description.

The url and basic parameters do return the full description. Like in: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/DaveDays/uploads?v=2&start-index=1&max-results=50

The add of the other parameters seems to be the cause.

But, "time=this_week" seems to give the longer description:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/DaveDays/uploads?v=2&start-index=1&max-results=50&time=this_week

Since its about the uploads of one channel, an option could be to get all videos first and do ordering and/or filtering yourself, later.